# How to get rid of buggy IntelliJ IDEA dialog that won't go away?

Tags: gnome, graphics, java

This is a bug I run into every couple of days, with [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)'s "Go to Class..." (or "Go to File...") dialog.

Usually it closes normally (when a class is selected or Esc pressed), but sometimes the popup is left behind, in the middle of the screen, on top of everything else. Even when I quit (or kill) IDEA completely, it stays. Example of what it looks like:

[image]

Only way I've found to get rid of it is **logging out completely** and then back in (i.e. restart X / GNOME). But having to do that is very annoying, as it can take 10 minutes or whatever to save (and re-setup afterwards) everything I have open.

**Is there any other way to get rid of the buggy popup dialog, while remaining logged in?** (Such as restarting some GNOME or X service / process.)

---

Using Ubuntu 11.04 and GNOME (not Unity).

IntelliJ IDEA ultimate edition 10.5, running on Sun's JDK 1.6.0_26 (i.e. `sun-java6-jdk` version 6.26-2natty1)

Some info about the graphics driver:

```
$ jockey-text -l
xorg:fglrx - ATI/AMD proprietary FGLRX graphics driver (Proprietary, Disabled, Not in use)
```

And:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: RV730 PRO [Radeon HD 4650]
       vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0100000-f010ffff ioport:1100(size=256) memory:f0120000-f013ffff
```

Answer (score 6):

I asked on Twitter, and one of IntelliJ IDEA developers ([Denis Zhdanov](https://twitter.com/denzhdanov)) [replied](https://twitter.com/el_joni/status/233197724579807232):

> I've encountered it under my ubuntu as well. Looks like a native
>   problem because it persisted even after killing all java processes
>
> I switched to java7 and [Xrender pipeline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#xrender) eventually and don't observe
>   the problem so far

I'm now trying if this helps, and will report back later. To recap, this is what I did:

1. Switched to running IDEA on [JRE 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). (If unsure of Java version used, check the Help -> About dialog.)
2. Set the property `-Dsun.java2d.xrender=true`. As Denis points out, the best way is to edit the file `<idea_home>/bin/idea.properties` and add `sun.java2d.xrender=true` on a new line.

Comment: It's recommended to configure IJ properties via $IJ_HOME/bin/idea.properties file, i.e. just add the following line  to it: sun.java2d.xrender=True

Comment: Any idea if this is specific to 11.04 or can we generalize the tags on this question?

Comment: Can't be sure about that. Just can say that I observed the problem only under 11.x and 12.x IJ versions.

Comment: @denis: Also affects IJ 10.x which I'm using. (I don't know either if this is Ubuntu 11.04 specific or not.)

Comment: Apparently this doesn't (always) help. :( Just now I ran into the bug again (after almost 2 weeks of using IDEA and not seeing it). Cc: @denis.zhdanov

Answer (score 1):

Run `xkill` from the "Run command" window, which can be invoked using alt+f2. Next, click the popup and its process should be killed.

Now, of course, this appears to be a bug in the application. I recommend you report it to the developers.

Comment: No, `xkill` doesn't work - the click "goes through" to the GNOME desktop (which seems to get reloaded somehow). Sorry, forgot to mention that I've tried this.

Comment: (The bug could be in many places: in the application, in Java's Swing (in which it is implemented afaik), the graphics card driver, etc. Quite possibly this only happens with some unfortunate combination of hardware and software.) But yeah, might be worth having a look at IDEA forums/bug tracker - maybe they know a workaround.